# MvcSiteMapProvider Menu with Filter Attributes in the Controller Class in Asp.Net Mvc 5

Tags: c#, menu, asp.net-mvc-5.1, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using this lib: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider

I want to have a menu structure like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Stuff</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/Stuff/"<li>
            <li><a href="/Stuff/Add"<li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am using MvcSiteMapNode without xml; just with the decorator's way.

So I have this Controller:

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Stuff", ParentKey = "root", Key = "stuff-key", Url = "#", ImageUrl = "fa-stuff")] 
public class StuffController : Controller {

    [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "List", ParentKey = "stuff-key", Key = "stuff-list")]
    public ActionResult Index(){}

    [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Add", ParentKey = "stuff-key", Key = "stuff-add")]
    public ActionResult Add(){}
}
```

My problem is that when I GET the url /Stuff/ the index node is not selected and is only selected the parent node(stuff-key). Even when I GET /Stuff/Index happens the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems here:

1. There is a bug that you have just uncovered (thanks) which allows matching on route values when the URL is set explicitly or when the node is non-clickable.
2. The character "#" is not technically allowed to be a URL. You can, but this will have the effect of going to "/#" (the home page), which is probably not what you wanted.

I am guessing for the second issue you wanted to make a node for grouping purposes, in which case it should be made non-clickable.

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Stuff", ParentKey = "root", Key = "stuff-key", Clickable = false, ImageUrl = "fa-stuff")]
```

This makes it generate plain text for "Stuff", not a hyperlink.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="/" title="Home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        Stuff
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/Stuff" title="List">List</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/Stuff/Add" title="Add">Add</a>
            </li>
        </ul>        
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, do note the matching problem won't go away until I get the patch released. So it won't work right until a version higher than 4.5.1 is available.

Comment: "This makes it generate plain text for "Stuff", not a hyperlink"
I think this isn't going to be a problem. I might fix it in the template.

Comment: Version 4.5.2 has been released with the patch. Modifying the template to output an anchor in the case where it is not clickable is pretty straightforward. You might also want to use a custom attribute so it doesn't do it for every non-clickable node, though.